Transfer files from NAS drive to AWS s3 using python scripts
I want to transfer daily files from the NAS drive to s3 regularly. I'm trying to establish a connection to the NAS shared drive and pull the data daily with Python script, but I couldn't establish the connection to the NAS drive from the AWS ec2 instance.
I established the same connection in my local with NAS credentials, and I'm able to connect my local machine with NAS drive and pull the data into my local machine, but the same thing is not working with EC2.
I’ve set up inbound and outbound security rules with smb 445.
 from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
 conn = SMBConnection('userxxx', 'pwdyyy', 'xxxx', 'yyyy',use_ntlm_v2=True,is_direct_tcp=True)
 conn.connect('servername',445)

Here's the error message when I try to attempt NAS drive:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 120, in connect
 self.sock = socket.create_connection(( ip, port ), timeout = timeout)
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Any suggestions?

Your NAS is presumably on your corporate network and is not accessible from the Internet. You will either need to perform the transfer from a computer on your corporate network, or the NAS will need to be accessible from the Internet.

You can try this tool WSF
A Peer-to-Peer File Transfer Tool Using WebRTC
